# 同じカラムに二種類のデータを取得する方法

Tags: sql, postgresql

### 実行したいこと

検索条件にはテーブルteiki．teiki_oyaprod_cdのteikioya1を使って理想実行結果のようなデータを取得したいです。
追記:
teiki.teiki_oyaprod_cdに加えてteikimeisai.teikiprod_cd(wa,wbs,wc)も検索時の条件に加えられるようになりました。自分なりにも解決できるかも知れませんがアドバイス等頂けたら幸いです。

- 理想実行結果のmeisaiにはteikimeisai.meisai_noでセット子情報の場合はNULL
- prod_cdには定期明細のteikiprod_cdもしくはteikiprod_cdの値がテーブルsetのset_oyaprod_cdに存在していればsetdetailのセット子情報set_prod_cdの値も取得してくる。セット子情報の並び順はsetdetailのseq昇順。
- prod_nmにはテーブルprod.prod_nameの値
- prod_priceにはテーブルprod.prod_priceの値でセット子情報のレコードの場合NULL
- ソート順はteikimeisai.meisai_no,setdetail.seq

### 詰まった点

セット親の商品コードとセット子の商品コードを別レコードの同じカラムprod_cdで取得する方法が分からず詰まってしまいました。

まだSQL経験も浅く、質問も初なので不明瞭な点、申し訳ありません。分かる方、ご教授頂きたいです。
PostgreSQLを利用しています。

#### テーブル名:prod

| prod_cd | prod_name | prod_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| wa | 定期1子A | 1000 |
| wbs | 定期1子Bセット親 | 2000 |
| wb1 | セット子B1 | 1000 |
| wb2 | セット子B2 | 1000 |
| wc | 定期1子C | 1000 |
| wds | 定期2子Dセット親 | 1000 |
| wd1 | セット子D1 | 1000 |
| teikioya1 | 定期親1 | 3000 |
| teikioya2 | 定期親2 | 3000 |

#### テーブル名:teiki

| teiki_cd | teiki_oyaprod_cd |
| --- | --- |
| teiki1 | teikioya1 |
| teiki2 | teikioya2 |

#### テーブル名:teikimeisai

| teiki_cd | meisai_no | teikiprod_cd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| teiki1 | 1 | wa |
| teiki1 | 2 | wbs |
| teiki1 | 3 | wc |
| teiki2 | 1 | wds |

#### テーブル名:setprod

| set_oyaprod_cd |
| --- |
| wbs |
| wds |

#### テーブル名:setdetail

| set_oyaprod_cd | seq | set_prod_cd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| wbs | 1 | wb1 |
| wbs | 2 | wb2 |
| wds | 1 | wd1 |

### 理想実行結果A

| meisai | prod_cd | prod_nm | prod_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | wa | 定期1子A1000 |  |
| 2 | wbs | 定期1子Bセット親 | 2000 |
|  | wb1 | セット子B1 |  |
|  | wb2 | セット子B2 |  |
| 3 | wc | 定期1子C | 1000 |

### 理想実行結果B (Aの代わりにこちらでも構わない)

| meisai | prod_cd | set_prod_cd | prod_nm | prod_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | wa |  | 定期1子A | 1000 |
| 2 | wbs |  | 定期1子Bセット親 | 2000 |
|  |  | wb1 | セット子B1 |  |
|  |  | wb2 | セット子B2 |  |
| 3 | wc |  | 定期1子C | 1000 |

---

## 追記：

以下はかなり理想実行結果Aに近くなりましたが、teikimeisai．teikiprod_cdの重複データがあるなど不完全で、これ以上の改善策が分からない状態です。

### 現状コード

```
select tm.meisai_no meisai,

       p.prod_cd,

       p.prod_name prod_nm,

       case when ssd.set_oyaprod_cd is null

            then p.prod_price

            else null

       end prod_price

from   prod        p

       left join teikimeisai tm

       on p.prod_cd = tm.teikiprod_cd

       left join setdetail sd

       on p.prod_cd = sd.set_prod_cd

       left join (select tm2.meisai_no,

                         tm2.set_oyaprod_cd,

                         sd2.set_prod_cd

                  from   teiki tk

                         join teikimeisai tm2

                         on tk.teiki_cd = tm2.teiki_cd

                         left join setprod sp

                         on tm2.teiki_prod_cd = sp.set_oyaprod_cd

                         left join setdetail sd2

                         on sp.set_oyaprod_cd = sd2.set_oyaprod_cd

                         where tk.teiki_cd = 'teikioya1') as ssd

       on p.prod_cd = ssd.sed_prod_cd

       on p.prod_cd = ssd.prod_cd

order by coalesce(tm.meisai_no, ssd.meisai_no),

         ssd.seq nulls first
```

Answer (score 1):

`prod.prod_cd`が`teikimeisai.teikiprod_cd`に存在するレコードを「セット親」と推測します。
セット親とセット子は別テーブルを参照するため左外部結合を使うのが通常の解法です。
さらにセット子は複数のテーブルを結合するため、`join`文の中で副問い合わせを併用することになります。

下記のサンプルコードを参考にしてみてください。

**サンプルコード**

**Schema (PostgreSQL v14)**

```
CREATE TABLE prod (
  "prod_cd" VARCHAR(100),
  "prod_name" VARCHAR(100),
  "prod_price" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO prod
  ("prod_cd", "prod_name", "prod_price")
VALUES
  ('wa', '商品A', '1000'),
  ('wbs', '商品Bセット', '2000'),
  ('wb1', '商品B1', '1000'),
  ('wb2', '商品B2', '1000'),
  ('wc', '商品C', '1000');

CREATE TABLE teiki (
  "teiki_cd" VARCHAR(100),
  "teiki_oyaprod_cd" VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO teiki
  ("teiki_cd", "teiki_oyaprod_cd")
VALUES
  ('teikia', 'teikioya');

CREATE TABLE teikimeisai (
  "teiki_cd" VARCHAR(100),
  "meisai_no" INTEGER,
  "teikiprod_cd" VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO teikimeisai
  ("teiki_cd", "meisai_no", "teikiprod_cd")
VALUES
  ('teikia', '1', 'wa'),
  ('teikia', '2', 'wbs'),
  ('teikia', '3', 'wc');

CREATE TABLE "set" (
  "set_oyaprod_cd" VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO set
  ("set_oyaprod_cd")
VALUES
  ('wbs');

CREATE TABLE setdetail (
  "set_oyaprod_cd" VARCHAR(100),
  "seq" INTEGER,
  "sed_prod_cd" VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO setdetail
  ("set_oyaprod_cd", "seq", "sed_prod_cd")
VALUES
  ('wbs', '1', 'wb1'),
  ('wbs', '2', 'wb2');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select tm.meisai_no meisai,
       p.prod_cd,
       p.prod_name prod_nm,
       case when ssd.set_oyaprod_cd is null
            then p.prod_price
            else null
       end prod_price
from   prod        p
       left join teikimeisai tm
       on p.prod_cd = tm.teikiprod_cd
       left join (select tm2.meisai_no,
                         s.set_oyaprod_cd,
                         sd.seq,
                         sd.sed_prod_cd
                  from   "set" s
                         join teikimeisai tm2
                         on s.set_oyaprod_cd = tm2.teikiprod_cd
                         join setdetail sd
                         on s.set_oyaprod_cd = sd.set_oyaprod_cd) as ssd
       on p.prod_cd = ssd.sed_prod_cd
order by coalesce(tm.meisai_no, ssd.meisai_no),
         ssd.seq nulls first;
```

| meisai | prod_cd | prod_nm | prod_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | wa | 商品A | 1000 |
| 2 | wbs | 商品Bセット | 2000 |
|  | wb1 | 商品B1 |  |
|  | wb2 | 商品B2 |  |
| 3 | wc | 商品C | 1000 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h1zs9rZ6HV7VNaWAZLcJnS/0)

**注記**

テーブル`teiki`の`teiki_oyaprod_cd`の必要性が読み取れなかったので使っていません。
`prod`テーブル`wc`レコードの`prod_price`が1000ですので、理想実行結果の1500とは異なります。
本テーブルは別名と思いますが、`set`のようにSQL文の構文そのものの単語は使わない方が可読性や保守性が上がります。

さて、スタックオーバーフローへようこそ！
仕様を詳細に書いていただくことは必要かつありがたいのですが、どちらかというと詰まった点や試行錯誤した痕跡に重点をおいて記載していただくと適切な回答がつきやすくなります。
※仕様と希望する動作のみ書かれた質問は、俗に「丸投げ」といわれる印象を与えてしまいます。

動かないSQL文であっても、SQLのコメントに `-- ここが分からない` などの注釈付きで載せた方が回答者の解説が実態に即したものになりますので、この回答が不適切な場合や今後の質問で意識していただければ幸いです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

join文の中で副問い合わせを併用することや
ソート順のcoalesceやnulls firstといった処理、大変勉強になりました。

またスタックオーバーフローのより良い使い方をご教授いただきありがとうございます。
今後、出来る限り自分で実施し不明点を具体的なものにして丸投げとならないように気を付けます。

今回ご回答いただいて、大変勉強になったのですが、自分の伝え方が非常に不明瞭だった故
誤解を与えてしまいました、申し訳ありません。
省いてしまっていたのですがprodの商品は今回取得したいデータ以外にも複数あり尚且つ、
取得方法はteiki.teiki_oyaprod_cdの値を検索条件（今回だとteiki．teiki_oyaprod_cdのteikioya1）にして
取得することを想定しておりました。より実態に即したデータに更新させていただきます。
今回ご教授頂いた内容を元に自分なりに現状のコードを作ってみまして
かなり理想に近くなってきましたがまだ不完全な状態です。
一度お答えして頂いた中恐縮ですが、お手すきの際に再度ご教授お願い致します。

Comment: こちら、ご教授頂いたものを活かしてSQLを作っていった所、理想結果通りの取得が無事出来ました。たくさんの学びがありました、ありがとうございます。